# C++ how to create a array of subclass use baseclass

Tags: c++

suppose I have three class like these:

```
class base {
//some data
method();
};

class sub1 : base {
//some data
//overrides base method
method();
};

class sub2: base {
//some data
//overrides base methods
method();
};
```

How can I create a array mixed with `sub1` and `sub2`? then calling subclass method with `base`?

Comment: you cannot call subclass method in base, you can call base class methods in subclass but not the other way around

Comment: You'll find all that in a good C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's sort this out. First of all, you probably meant `virtual method();`, probably with a return type, maybe with parameters. Without virtual, base class pointers and references won't know about the overridden method. Second, make the destructor virtual. Do this until you know why you need to (`delete (base*) new derived;`) - then keep doing this until all your neighbourhood knows why you need to. Third, the sad thing is, all std. C++ containers are homogeneous (non-std. heterogeneous container-like objects in Boost exist), thus you need to find an object that's common and that's somehow able to handle these types. Common choices are:

- Common base class pointer, in your case, `base*`. This conventionally owns the objects and is manually (de)allocated (that is, you need to call `new` and `delete`). This is the most common choice. You might try smart pointers later, but let's get the basics first.
- Common base class reference, in your case, `base&`. Common convention is that this doesn't own the object (albeit this is not a language restriction), thus it's mainly used for referring to objects that are stored in another container. Since you need to store them somewhere, I wouldn't opt for this now, but it might come handy later.
- `std::variant<>` (or `boost::variant<>`), this is a discriminated union, that is, a class that stores one and only one of the listed items *and* knows which one it stores. You don't need a common base class, but even if you have one, it's cool because it tends to store objects locally, thus *might* be faster when you have enough cache.
- `union`, which is like variant, but does not know the type being stored. Local storage is guaranteed, as well as UB if you write one field and read another
- Compiler-specific solutions. If you *know* that your classes are of the same size (in this case, they are) and you *know for sure* that you have untyped memory, then you might store the base class and it'll 'just work', provided you always take the address and `->` operator. Note that this is UB squared, I just list this because you'll likely encounter similar code. Also note that simply having a `union` does not remove UB in this case - until we have access to virtual table pointer, this can only be done by manually handling virtual functions.

Comment: I tried union, it doesn't work, because the struct and class has non-trivil constructors and operators, says compiler.

Comment: @Xeechem: so define the corresponding (delegate) constructor for the given type

Comment: well, that depends on your application, in my case, the interface of subclasses should look same.

Comment: @Xeechem: no, I mean union's constructor (for the given type(s) ).

Comment: Ha, thanks, but how do you define a constructor in a union for multiple classes?